# Cannot Implicitly convert anonymoustype#1 to Object

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, lambda, type-conversion

I am trying to JOIN with LINQ & Lambda. But Getting an error stating Cannot Implicitly convert anonymoustype#1 to BRAND_NAME_MAP_ID. I am fairly new to Lambdas and stuck here.

```
public BRAND_NAME_MAP_MASTER GetBrandNameBrandNameMapID(int BrandNameMapID)
{
    PFC_BRAND_NAME_MAP_MASTER objBrandNameMap = Db.PFC_BRAND_NAME_MAP_MASTERs
        .Join(SIRDC.INGREDIENT_BRAND_NAME_MAPs,
              a => a.BRAND_NAME_MAP_ID, 
              b => b.BRAND_NAME_MAP_ID,
              (a, b) => new {a, b})
        .Where(x => x.a.BRAND_NAME_MAP_ID == PFCBrandNameMapID)
        .FirstOrDefault(); //Getting error here

    return objPFCBrandNameMap;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query is returning an anonymous type containing two properties, `a` is a `PFC_BRAND_NAME_MAP_MASTER` and `b` is a `INGREDIENT_BRAND_NAME_MAP`. It looks like you only need the first property so just add a `Select` to get at it:

```
PFC_BRAND_NAME_MAP_MASTER objBrandNameMap = Db.PFC_BRAND_NAME_MAP_MASTERs
    .Join(SIRDC.INGREDIENT_BRAND_NAME_MAPs,
          a => a.BRAND_NAME_MAP_ID, 
          b => b.BRAND_NAME_MAP_ID,
          (a, b) => new {a, b})
    .Where(x => x.a.BRAND_NAME_MAP_ID == PFCBrandNameMapID)
    .Select(x => x.a) /Add this line
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: thanks david that worked beautifully. Never had a answer this quick ever before.